# C: transitive (double) assignments

Tags: c, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I have used such construct in C:

```
list->head = list->tail = NULL;
```

and now I consider whether this really mean what I suppose.

Is this mean?

1. `list->head = NULL; list->tail = NULL;`

or

2. `list->head = list->tail; list->tail = NULL;`

thx for clarifying

Comment: Read it right to left.

Comment: Formally none of them!

Comment: Really the answer is just don't do that. If you need to set two pointers to null, do it on separate lines. Then anyone from any programming background can instantly see what was intended and what the code does.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of those is correct.

Since the simple assignment `=` operator is right-to-left associative, your expression is identical to:

```
list->head = (list->tail = NULL);
```

NULL is assigned to tail, and then tail, which has the value of a null pointer, to head.

Comment: Yeah I mean but this too option rather what will be the result not the sequence of assignment. So 1) option will be the correct one as both will have NULL pointers. Thx for further clarifying

Comment: @MichałZiobro Option 1 has a sequence point which isn't present in the example.

Comment: I would really like to read constructive criticism along with the downvotes.

Comment: Sorry, had to edit to remove the DV. I thought there is a problem with `volatile`. Checked the standard. While there is a problem indeed, the standard does not define how to resolve it, leaving your answer **mostly** correct. But as a consequence, this should never be used with `volatile` qualified objects!

Comment: @Olaf Why would it be a problem?

Comment: See 6.5.16p3 . Basically, the standard leaves reading `list->tail` or using the assigned value without read to the implementation. That makes your answer only "mostly correct", but can mess up `volatile`s (footnote 111 implies the implementation even may decide per-expression). I thought it requires `volatile` to be read, that's why I DVd initially. But after I started my own answer, I checked back in the standard and saw this - unpleasant - description. Imo this is a defect in the standard. Maybe I should check if there is a report already. Until fixed, just don't use that for `volatile`s

Comment: @Olaf I don't follow, can you elaborate.

Comment: @2501: Simply: `tail` can be written, then read or only written and the value passed on to the left `=`'s RHS. I thought it must not read after the write. That is important for e.g. write-only peripheral registers. As-is now, that may result in storing an indeterminate value to `head`.

Comment: @Olaf What is `='s RHS`?

Comment: **R**ight **H**and **S**ide of the assignment operator `=`

Comment: @Olaf  I still don't understand what are you trying to say, and what the actual problem is. All I gathered so far is that there is something with volatile, but what exactly remains a mistery.

Comment: Hmm, on third thought, I think the DVs were justified. All answers are incorrect or at least incomplete.

Comment: @2501: I explained good enough and provided exactly what is the problem. Please try to understand. If you never worked with `volatile`, you might need to read about it's implications first. Note there is a defect report about the description of `volatile`, read it, too (it actually agrees with the current implementation in all modern compilers.).

Comment: @Olaf I'm especially puzzled what does volatile have to do with this question, since that is not the problem at all. OP is merely curious about the order of assignment. If you think there is something wrong with volatile in C, post a report, or ask a new question and answer it so everyone can benefit from your findings.

Comment: We don't have the declaration. If `tail` is declared `volatile`, OP may a problem with the answers (it is not just your's), depending in the compiler, code-flow, etc. I described very clearly what can happen. If you don't see why that is a problem with `volatile`, see what `volatile` implies! Btw., it is your description which is wrong/incomplete, not the code you show. The description is not what the standard writes.

Comment: @Olaf Post a self answered post instead of hiding this information in comments on an unrelated question. Others would like to benefit from you knowledge of volatile.

Comment: It very well is relevant for this question! If you don't understand does not mean it is not. The question clearly asks how the expression is evaluated, which you did not answer correctly considering the standard. Did you even read the section of the standard IO referenced? And the footnote?

Answer (score 3):

The assignment operator is right to left associative.

Thus this expression statement

```
list->head = list->tail = NULL;
```

is equivalent to

```
list->tail = NULL;
list->head = list->tail;
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them. It mean

```
list->tail = NULL;
list->head = list->tail;
```

1 is incorrect because in case the type of `list->tail` is not a pointer, it may yield different result because the value will be converted to the type of the destination of the assignment.

The order of two statements in 2 is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, had to edit to remove the DV. I thought there is a problem with `volatile`. Checked the standard. While there is a problem indeed, the standard does not define how to resolve it, leaving your answer **mostly** correct. But as a consequence, this should never be used with `volatile` qualified objects!

Answer (score 1):

it's multiple assignment as your first option is the right one

```
list->head = list->tail = NULL;
```

it's a magic of flow.

initially ,`tail` is set to `NULL` ,starting from right to left

```
list->tail = NULL;
```

then 
`list->head = list->tail ;`

now `tail` is `NULL` so the `head` will also assigned a `NULL` value

Answer (score 0):

Associativity of assignment operator `=` is right to left. This means that if there are more than one `=` operator in a statement, then the rightmost is evaluated first, then the one left to it, and in that order, untill the leftmost `=` operator is evaluated at last.

This means that when you do

```
list->head = list->tail = NULL;
```

the right most assignment, i.e. `list->tail = NULL` is evaluated first. So `list->tail` will be `NULL`.

After that `list->head = list->tail` will be evaluated. And since `list->tail` is `NULL` by now (because of previous evaluation- i.e. `list->tail = NULL`), now `list->head` is also `NULL`.

Based on how you are representing in your question, it is like

```
list->tail = NULL; list->head = list->tail;
```

Comment: `NULL` is a macro, not a value.

Comment: Sorry, had to edit to remove the DV. I thought there is a problem with volatile. Checked the standard. While there is a problem indeed, the standard does not define how to resolve it, leaving your answer **mostly** correct. But as a consequence, this should never be used with volatile qualified objects!

Comment: @Olaf Agreed, I should have been careful with the words there. Anycase, just wondering, can we use NULL as identifier ? Like `struct node *NULL = &node;` ? I mean is it possible to use `NULL` which is not a macro?

Comment: @sps:  It's possible with some preprocessor gymnastics, but it's a ***really bad idea***.  `NULL` has a very specific meaning in C, and using it for any other purpose will confuse the heck out of anyone reading your code.

Comment: @JohnBode I agree - that using NULL for any other purpose is a bad idea - but was just wondering if  `NULL is a macro, not a value` is a `convention` or a `fact`/`standard`.

Comment: A macro is an identifier of the preprocessor only. It just does not exist for the normal compiler. (And you shall not use it as one either). AFAIK the standard does not allow to redefine these macros by an application. As @JohnBode wrote: this is a strict **no-go** (I'd seriously kick buts if I ever see such hacks from co-workers)! And yes, it is a macro. Feel free to look up yourself in the standard. It is not that hard to read/understand.

Comment: @sps: it's standard.  See  7.19 of the [online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C 2011 standard.

Comment: @Olaf Changed `will have value NULL` to `will be NULL`. @John Bode thanks for the draft link.

Comment: That is not a bit better! As said, `NULL` is a macro. A pointer cannot "be" a macro. It need not even have the same value. You might want to read about _null pointers_ and _null pointer constants_.

Comment: @Olaf Yes NULL is a macro, but the preprocessor transofrms NULL to some text that is `#defined` as NULL. So when I say pointer becomes NULL, it mean pointer becomes - or is equal to - what is represented by that text. Just like when we do `if (node == NULL)`, we are not comparing with macro - but with the value, that is represented by the text, that is `#defined` as NULL. I said I agree that the words may not be correct - in strict grammatical sense -, but I hope that saying a pointer is NULL conveys the intended message.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, I mean `#define NULL 0 /* or whatever */` - not vice versa - that was my mistake. I've already said that the words may not be correct - in strict grammatical sense - so I am not trying to mislead, I too am concerned, like you, that sb could misunderstand so accept that wording may not be correct. As I said that a `pointer is NULL` gives the intended meaning, by which I stand by. You may disagree and its upto you. Reading standard-agreed. In programming you have to be exact-yes, but while explaining a concept in english, not so - untill the listener gets the intent.

Comment: Typically in C, it is `#define ((void *)0)` to make sure it is a pointer. `0` is valid, too and that has been used in C++ until C++11 (well, it still exists, but is deprecated - should be in C, too - blame that over-emphasised backwards compatibility policy). I did not say you misslead intentionally, but your texts are missleading. But as you seem to insist keeping that missleading wording - despite you were told it is and **why**, I might have to reconsider. Just that: this is read by beginners, who take this literally. If that is no reason to be precise, idk. You challenge other questions.

Answer (score -6):

With all the incomplete answers, I have to clarify this a bit.

First, the expression is evaluated right to left:

```
list->head = (list->tail = NULL);
```

The standard defines the [behaviour of the assignment operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p3) as:

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,111) but is not an lvalue. The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion. The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands. The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.

Problem is now, the standard leaves **two ways** how to get the value of an assignment.**

```
// variant 1 (read the left-hand side after writing it)
list->tail = NULL;
list->head = list->tail;
```

That is, `list->tail` is read after it got its value and that value is assigned to `list->head`.

```
// variant 2 (use temporary storage)
typeof(list->tail) temp = NULL;  // get the value/type of the RHS of the inner assignment
list->tail = temp;
list->head = temp;
```

(RHS: right hand side, the term to the right of an operator). Thanks, to @chux, the two assignments could also be swapped.

See [footnote 111](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note111):

> The implementation is permitted to read the object to determine the value but is **not required to, even when the object has volatile-qualified type**.

---

The variants behave equivalent with respect of the abstract machine - **unless `list->tail` is qualified `volatile`** (more general: any but the leftmost object). Briefly, `volatile` tells the compiler the access to an object has side-effects. It is typically used for peripheral hardware registers, e.g. USART. While it is rarely (and if, then often wrongly) used in desktop applications, it is typically used in OS kernel-drivers and bare-metal embedded systems.

Writes and reads to such registers typically pass the data written to the (external) hardware, resp. a read yields the value of such a hardware register. Worse, these registers can be write-only or read-only. For write-only, reading yields indeterminate values which is not related to what was written. Relevant here is that accesses to these objects have to be very carefully controlled and sequenced. There mut be no unexpected read or write.

So, consider the code above. Then the variants will generate different accesses to the hardware:

- Variant 1 will result in a write, followed by a read. If the register is
  write-only, the read yields unrelated data. That is likely not what we want.
- Variant 2 will only write, but reuse the value written for the second assignment.
- Variant 2 has indeterminate sequence of the order the writes are performed, wich is another concern with `volatile` lvalues.

Note which variant is used is not detrmined by the user, but the compiler. It might even vary for different expressions in the code.

As a consequence, chained assignments are a no-go once `volatile` is involved.

Comment: Anyone not understanding the difference is kindly requested to comment for clarification before downvoting!

Comment: Maybe you could clarify which object exactly must be defined with volatile to get this problem, the first or second member or the entire struct. (I didn't downvote.)

Comment: @2501: Good point, edited. Hope you now understand what I meant. Re the DV: yes, I have the impression there is someone after me; got most of my newer answer DVd. Must be some jerk, either not knowing C, understanding my answers (that's why I commented to comment), or just bullying. Some people don't know the difference between open words in a discussion and school playground.

Comment: Concerning a variation on variant 2.  Could not code do `list->head = temp; list->tail = temp;`?  (assign `head` first`)

Comment: @chux: That would change the order of the assignments for `volatile` lvalues. Hmm, there is no sequence point in-between, so this would be another concern with the nested assignments. I'll add that, it just adds to the problems, though.

Comment: If `list->head` and `list->tail` point to the same object, it invokes UB and doesn't fall under the said "variants".

Comment: @P.P.: Unlikely, even presuming `*list` is the same object. How would you construct this without illegal casts? (if `list == NULL`, this is UB, too. or `list` has a different type, or ...)

Comment: @Unlikely is not same as never, is it? The reasons you said in the `(..)` is also possible. I know this whole thing is extremely pedantry. But there's not much of an option left to deal with the "technically correct" and "I know this won't work when..." sort of people. Considering the sort of objection you have made, I am sure you'll find this line of reasoning quite appealing.

Comment: @P.P.: I talk about a very real scenario with **valid** code. You talk about code which is invalid as such. I don't think this is comparable. You would know if you had some experience in the embedded world. But maybe you are that kind of people who cannot accept they are wrong.